# Read in text not the same as assigned text

Tags: java, string, encoding, fonts, character-encoding

I have a problem that should be simple. I must be missing something fundamental. I create a String viz.

```
String text = "\u0391\u039A\u03C1\u1F83\uA978\u0370\u03D8\u03C0";
```

If I use that as the argument to a JLabel with the default font, it prints Greek characters as I'd like.

However, if I put that same string (with no quotes, of course) into a text file and read that line in and assign the line to a JLabel, I get the "uninterpreted" string. It looks just like it is in the file. I've tried using different encodings to read the file like ISO-8859-1, UTF-8, UTF-16, etc. to no avail.

How do I get the read in text to be just like an assigned piece of text?

Try

```
String text = "\u0391\u039A\u03C1\u1F83\uA978\u0370\u03D8\u03C0";
System.out.println( "As ascii text = " + text );
```

and

```
String label = new String( readLabel( directory + File.separator
+ "testReadLabel.txt" ) );
System.out.println( "As ascii label = " + label );
```

When testReadLabel.txt contains the text above and the read is a standard

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(
new FileInputStream( fileName ), "ISO-8859-1" ) );

return br.readLine();
```

Comment: Why are you putting Java string literal escapes in a file? You should put the actual characters.

Answer (score 1):

You must *unescape* the string first after you did read it from the file. You could e.g. use the [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) from [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi) to do this:

```
String label = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(stringFromFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Backslash escape codes are translated in string literals by the compiler. They are not translated in file IO. If you want to parse the escape codes, you'll have to do that yourself or use a library to do it for you.

Comment: Got it!  I was not reading actual Unicode bytes from the file, but rather ascii text with escape codes that produce the Greek characters when translated by the compiler.  If I had written out the original text as Unicode, I should have been able to read it back in and have it print the same way, but I would not have been able to "see" it in the file looking like the original literal.  It would have been a series of bytes representing the Unicode.